# How to adjust the font and font color over a particular region?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

How to adjust the font,font color and font size over a particular region in oracle apex? I tried to find a particular option to adjust but failed. Do i need to use javascript or CSS for adjustment of this type ?

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you use CSS style. You can write your CSS in page designers CSS sections inline field for related region. If you click on specific region in page designer, you can find Custom Attribute field under Advance section. You can put your CSS there either. Hope this helps.